# Concurrency - A monitor that implements semaphores

Tags: c, concurrency, monitor, semaphore

I need help constructing a monitor that implements a semaphore, and simple C example will do.

This is to demonstrate that a monitor can be used any place a semaphore can be used.

Comment: Is it OK to use condition variables?

Comment: The [Wikipedia page on Monitors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29) includes such an example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you say mutex/condvars are allowed, then check this:

```
#include <pthread.h>

typedef struct
{
  unsigned int count;
  pthread_mutex_t lock;
  pthread_cond_t cond;
} semaph_t;

int
semaph_init (semaph_t *s, unsigned int n)
{
  s->count = n;
  pthread_mutex_init (&s->lock, 0);
  pthread_cond_init (&s->cond, 0);
  return 0;
}

int
semaph_post (semaph_t *s)
{
  pthread_mutex_lock (&s->lock); // enter monitor
  if (s->count == 0)
    pthread_cond_signal (&s->cond); // signal condition
  ++s->count;
  pthread_mutex_unlock (&s->lock); // exit monitor
  return 0;
}

int
semaph_wait (semaph_t *s)
{
  pthread_mutex_lock (&s->lock); // enter monitor
  while (s->count == 0)
    pthread_cond_wait (&s->cond, &s->lock); // wait for condition
  --s->count;
  pthread_mutex_unlock (&s->lock); // exit monitor
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the main answer on the [Wikipedia article regarding monitors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29).

```
monitor class Semaphore
{
  private int s := 0
  invariant s >= 0
  private Condition sIsPositive /* associated with s > 0 */

  public method P()
  {
    if s = 0 then wait sIsPositive
    assert s > 0
    s := s - 1
  }

  public method V()
  {
    s := s + 1
    assert s > 0
    signal sIsPositive
  }
}
```